# jQuery tablesorter, numbered sorted columns

Tags: tablesorter

How do I numerate sorted columns?
If I click column "Date" need to numerate it 1, next click "Client" need to numerate it 2

This is my thead:

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Quotation No</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Client</th>
    <th>Manager</th>
    <th>Total amount</th>
    <th>Order</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

Example
http://i58.tinypic.com/2lszc0n.jpg

Comment: U-N-C-L-E-A-R, even after editing.

Comment: what do you mean? what is the problem you have hit and what have you tried

Comment: Example http://i58.tinypic.com/2lszc0n.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), you can use the following code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/112/)):

```
$(function () {
    $('table')
        .on('sortEnd', function(){
            var i,
                c = this.config,
                list = c.sortList;
            // clear indexes
            c.$headers.find('.index').text('');
            for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                c.$headers.eq( list[i][0] ).find('.index').text( i+1 );
            }
        })
        .tablesorter({
            theme: 'blue',
            headerTemplate: '{content}{icon}<span class="index"></span>',
            widgets: ['zebra']
        });
});
```

The result isn't exactly like you have in the example screenshot, but you can achieve it with a bit of css modification.

If you are using the original tablesorter, you can add the `<span class="index"></span>` to each header manually.